# get failed keys or their count from php memcached setMulti function

Tags: php, memcached

I try to set about a thousand keys inside memcached using `setMulti` function of PHP memcached lib. Now if one or more of the keys fail to set, then I want to know which of them failed or at least get count of failed keys.

In documentation however, it is given that setMulti returns only true or false. Is there any way by which I can come to know number of failed keys?

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a way to do this.  If the comment on the [`setMulti` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.setmulti.php) is correct, the internal implementation just calls `set` repeatedly.  You may as well do it by hand if this is the case.

Comment: I hate when people are not accepting the correct answer, when the correct answer is not what they expected!